# Cannot install redmine people plugin, error parsing Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I have been trying to install RedmineCRM People plugin, but I keep getting the below error when I run this command `bundle exec rake redmine:plugins NAME=redmine_people RAILS_ENV=production`:

```
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`:
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: Warning: this Gemfile contains
multiple primary sources. Each source after the first must include a block
to indicate which gems should come from that source. To downgrade this error
to a warning, run `bundle config --delete disable_multisource`. Bundler
cannot continue.

#  from /opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/redmine_people/Gemfile:1
#  -------------------------------------------
>  source 'https://rubygems.org'
#  gem "redmine_crm"
#  -------------------------------------------
. Bundler cannot continue.

#  from /opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/Gemfile:110
#  -------------------------------------------
#  Dir.glob File.expand_path("../plugins/*/{Gemfile,PluginGemfile}", __FILE__) do |file|
>    eval_gemfile file
#  end
#  -------------------------------------------
```

I followed the installation instructions but it didn't work, I would really like to know what I am doing wrong here.

I am running Redmine 3.2.0 (bitnami image) and below is the URL for the people plugin:
http://www.redminecrm.com/projects/people/pages/1

---

/opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/redmine_people/Gemfile contains:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem "redmine_crm"
gem "vcard", "~> 0.2.8"
gem "rake"
```

---

/opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/Gemfile contains:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

if Gem::Version.new(Bundler::VERSION) < Gem::Version.new('1.5.0')
abort "Redmine requires Bundler 1.5.0 or higher (you're using #
{Bundler::VERSION}).\nPlease update with 'gem update bundler'."
end

gem "rails", "4.2.5"
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 3.1.4"
gem "coderay", "~> 1.1.0"
gem "builder", ">= 3.0.4"
gem "request_store", "1.0.5"
gem "mime-types"
gem "protected_attributes"
gem "actionpack-action_caching"
gem "actionpack-xml_parser"
gem "roadie-rails"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin, :jruby]
gem "rbpdf", "~> 1.19.0"

# Optional gem for LDAP authentication
group :ldap do
gem "net-ldap", "~> 0.12.0"
end

# Optional gem for OpenID authentication
group :openid do
gem "ruby-openid", "~> 2.3.0", :require => "openid"
gem "rack-openid"
end

platforms :mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw do
# Optional gem for exporting the gantt to a PNG file, not supported with jruby
group :rmagick do
gem "rmagick", ">= 2.14.0"
end

# Optional Markdown support, not for JRuby
group :markdown do
gem "redcarpet", "~> 3.3.2"
end
end

platforms :jruby do
# jruby-openssl is bundled with JRuby 1.7.0
gem "jruby-openssl" if Object.const_defined?(:JRUBY_VERSION) && JRUBY_VERSION < '1.7.0'
gem "activerecord-jdbc-adapter", "~> 1.3.2"
end

# Include database gems for the adapters found in the database
# configuration file
require 'erb'
require 'yaml'
database_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "config/database.yml")
if File.exist?(database_file)
database_config = YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(database_file)).result)
adapters = database_config.values.map {|c| c['adapter']}.compact.uniq
if adapters.any?
adapters.each do |adapter|
  case adapter
  when 'mysql2'
    gem "mysql2", "0.3.14", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
    gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
  when 'mysql'
    gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
  when /postgresql/
    gem "pg", "~> 0.18.1", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
    gem "activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
  when /sqlite3/
    gem "sqlite3", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
    gem "jdbc-sqlite3", ">= 3.8.10.1", :platforms => :jruby
    gem "activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
  when /sqlserver/
    gem "tiny_tds", "~> 0.6.2", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
    gem "activerecord-sqlserver-adapter", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  else
    warn("Unknown database adapter `#{adapter}` found in config/database.yml, use Gemfile.local to load your own database gems")
  end
end
else
warn("No adapter found in config/database.yml, please configure it first")
end
else
warn("Please configure your config/database.yml first")
end

group :development do
gem "rdoc", ">= 2.4.2"
gem "yard"
end

group :test do
gem "minitest"
gem "rails-dom-testing"
gem "mocha"
gem "simplecov", "~> 0.9.1", :require => false
# For running UI tests
gem "capybara"
gem "selenium-webdriver"
end

local_gemfile = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "Gemfile.local")
if File.exists?(local_gemfile)
eval_gemfile local_gemfile
end

# Load plugins' Gemfiles
Dir.glob File.expand_path("../plugins/*/{Gemfile,PluginGemfile}", __FILE__) do |file|
eval_gemfile file
end
```

Comment: What does your Gemfile contain?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Updated Gemfile contents in original post.

Comment: Try to download new version of redmine_people, it's maybe fix issue.

Comment: @kunashir I have the latest version.

Comment: @M.S. I looked my installation and didn't find gem "rake"